# DAX Function for 'Customers also bought'

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular, powerbi-embedded

My Power BI dashboard contains a product filter and I would need to create a Power BI chart to show 'Customers who bought this product also bought the following ...'. Which would be a bar chart of the products by Price.

My data is flattened, consisting of an Orders table with the following:
Customer, Product, Price, Qty, Date.

Need help to build the DAX query for achieving this and handle the context correctly. I tried using ALL and FILTER but did not manage to get the correct result as yet.

Comment: I've never done this, so I'm not going to attempt to answer, but there's a comprehensive post about Basket Analysis by DAXPatterns.com, that covers "Products More Likely Bought with Another Product" (and other related scenarios): http://www.daxpatterns.com/basket-analysis/

Comment: Post relevant part of your tabular model (relevant tables, relationships, column names) and explain better what you want to achieve (describe it from SQL like approach). I will help you then write the DAX query that you need.